# Why does the regex "[a-z]" match against the non-ASCII characters "İıſK" when the case-insensitive flag is used?

Tags: unicode, python-re, python-unicode

The following Python code (version 3.11.0) gives an unexpected result:

```
import re
import sys

s = ''.join(map(chr, range(sys.maxunicode + 1)))
matches = ''.join(re.findall('[a-z]', s, re.IGNORECASE))
print(matches)
```

It prints the extra 4 non-ASCII characters `'İıſK'`:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzİıſK
```

This is actually [documented](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/re.html#re.IGNORECASE), but without any explanation as to why it behaves like this:

> Note that when the Unicode patterns [a-z] or [A-Z] are used in combination with the IGNORECASE flag, they will match the 52 ASCII letters and 4 additional non-ASCII letters: ‘İ’ (U+0130, Latin capital letter I with dot above), ‘ı’ (U+0131, Latin small letter dotless i), ‘ſ’ (U+017F, Latin small letter long s) and ‘K’ (U+212A, Kelvin sign). If the ASCII flag is used, only letters ‘a’ to ‘z’ and ‘A’ to ‘Z’ are matched.

I could maybe understand matching against the Kelvin sign, but the others make no sense to me. Is this just a bug or is there a deeper reason why it should behave like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those characters are considered (at least in some situations/locales) to be lower-/upper-case variants of the "traditional" ASCII a-z characters:

- [U+0130 Latin Capital Letter I with Dot Above `İ`](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+0130) is a upper-case variant of `i`
- Similarly [U+0131 Latin Small Letter Dotless I `ı`](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+0131) is considered the lower-case variant of `I`
- [U+017F Latin Small Letter Long S `ſ`](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+017F) is a lower-case variant of `S`
- [U+212A Kelvin Sign `K`](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+212A) is a upper-case variant of `k`

(See the "Uppercase Character" and "Lowercase Character" entries on these pages, which are directly taken from the Unicode data set).

**Why** are these "non-default" characters marked this way? Because *in some sense* or *in some locales* those are actually, valid relatives. For example due to the existence of the [Dotless I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotless_I) both dotted and dotless variants of I exist in upper and in lower case and [cause frequent problems in software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotted_and_dotless_I_in_computing). Similarly if you had a text that contained a ſ and you wanted to convert it to upper-case, then S would be the most appropriate candidate.